# How to generate and handle internal IDs in Microsoft Forms 365

Tags: outlook, office365, ms-forms

I am trying to implement an evaluation survey for meetings, using Microsoft Forms over Office 365.
After I create and generate the link, I can get the info in an Excel file, but am missing a field with which I can link the survey's answers to the meeting.

Desired output in as seen in this image (all fields are already generated by Forms, except by that whose content is highlighted in yellow, which is the one I need to find out how to generate):

[image: desired output]

For the time being, I have 2 issues to solve:

1. How can I generate an ID for a meeting from Microsoft Outlook (where the meeting invitation was sent).
2. How can I pass that ID to Microsoft Forms.

Ideas about this or an alternative approach are welcome, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a better approach:

- To **scrape** all appointments in a period of time via API
- To load appointment's data in MongoDB
- To send personalized links to Outlook Forms questionnaires.

Here is the API documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations